# I want to show info window of google map on top right corner of the google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show the info window on the top right corner of the map when user click on the any marker in google map.
Its info window should always show on the top right corner of the map.

```
     // Setting a custom info window adapter for the google map
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

        // Use default InfoWindow frame if return null
        // else inflate any layout
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

            /*showAlertToChooseImage();*/
            if (!marker.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Helipad")) {
                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.windowlayout, null);

                // Getting reference to the TextView to set latitude
                TextView tvGroupName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewGroupName);
                tvGroupName.setText(modelItemMarker.getIncidentGropName());
                // Getting reference to the TextView to set longitude
                TextView tvAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewAddress);
                tvAddress.setText(modelItemMarker.getLOCATION_ADDRESS());

                TextView tvDateTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDateTime);
                tvDateTime.setText(modelItemMarker.getIncidentDateTimeField());

                // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
                return view;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }
    });

    // Handle click of the infoWindow.
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(Constants.CallNO, modelItemMarker.getCadIdField());
            SideMenuFragment_Left.IsChangePwd = false;
            SideMenuFragment_Right.IsAgencies = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, IncidentDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.INCIDENT_DETAIL, bundle);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Can anybody please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: post your code here. what have you done till now and your implementations .

Comment: @SagarNayak I think that would help.

Comment: ok so what help do you need ? in xml ?

Comment: On click of marker info window opens.By default it opens just above the marker.I want to open that info window on the top right corner of the Map screen.

Comment: ok so marker info data is with you , i assume . and you can display it any where you want . right ?

Comment: Yes, I want to display it at Top right corner.

Answer (score 0):

try on this way .

```
public class MarkerDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    OnInfoWindowClickListener,
    OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;
    // Add markers to the map and do other map setup.
    ...
    // Set a listener for info window events.
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Info window clicked",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the above code you will get the info window top of the marker.But if you want to do top left corner i am thinking  you need to take one more layout and you have to add this layout to maps activity on clicking of marker.

Answer (score 0):

Current functions from Google Maps API for Android cannot achieve that. Try implementing it to your Android App using the [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#introduction) via a WebFrame instead.

You can use the `InfoWindowOptions` to customize the position by using the `pixelOffset` positions option
More info on that [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#add).